# Rename lots of txt file based on content criteria (Batch script help)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I have lots of *.txt Files in a folder.

The text file looks like  a dictionary where you have a some abbreviations
and the meaning of the word is next to it. For e.g.

file1.txt

```
aaa-bbb-ccc 
    = this is a abc
```

file2.txt

```
aa-dd-ee 
    = blah blah blah
```

file3.txt

```
aaa-ff-xxxx     
    = have a nice day
```

file4.txt

```
mm-aaa-xx 
    = batch script
```

etc..

The abbreviations :
    1. can  range between 2 to 4 characters it can be aaa,mm, or any text.
    2. most of them is in the second line as the first line is blank

I want to know if it is possible using batch 
script to go through that folder read the content of each file, 
and rename it as per the abbreviation. how to proceed?

aaa-bbb-ccc.txt

aa-dd-ee.txt

etc..

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a plain `for` loop to process each file. Use a `for /f` loop to process the lines in a file. As `for /f` ignores empty files, it doesn't matter, if the first line is empty or not:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
set "new="
for /f "usebackq delims==" %%b in ("%%a") do if not defined new set "new=%%b"
ECHO ren "%%a" "!new!%%~xa"
)
```

for more information, read `for /?`.

Note: for security reasons, the `ren` command is disabled by just echoing it to the screen. Remove `ECHO` once you verified, that the output is ok.

*EDIT*: the `=` might be on the same line. Or not... To solve it, use `delims==`. (If you get trouble with spaces, and there are *no spaces* in the abbreviations, extend `... delims== "`)

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for your reply. I run the code. It seems to be near. However, in many files, it is not able to process because the equal to sign and the details are on the same line. for example xxx-yyy-zzz = this on the same line.... is it possible to limit it up to the "=" sign ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephan!

 it works well.. Have a nice day